# Perl one liner + regular expression to match part of word

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell, ksh

I write Perl one liner code in order to match IP address according to the following rule:

match only the three first octets while the four octet must be valid 0-255 , additional to that number or "**.**" must not be exists before the first octet
and number or "**.**" must not be exist also after the four octet

example

```
 export IP=100.187.34
```

example of IP's that should matched

```
:100.187.34.12:.10
IP=100.187.34.100$
AAA100.187.34.199BBB
address:100.187.34.210+
```

example of IP's that shouldn't matched

```
 55.100.187.34.99
 .100.187.34..
 100.187.34.100.1
 100.187.34.2100
 1.100.187.34
 100.187.34.1.1
```

so this is my code (not work according to my rules):

```
      echo [...]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[...]   |    perl  -pe 'print if  /(?<![\d.])\Q$ENV{IP}\E(?=\.(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?!\d))/; '
```

the problem is my code matched almost any number

please advice what I need to fix in my code in order to match the IP's only according to the rules

Comment: split may be better option to filter by your rules.

Comment: Again? SO is not a code-writing service. This is the fourth time you've come to us to update your regex for you!

Comment: ok thx Ikegami - question sometimes can be diff with other conflicts ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples of IP regexp matching from O'Reilly's Regular Expressions Cookbook:

Simple regex to check for an IP address:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
```

Accurate regex to check for an IP address:

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}↵
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Simple regex to extract IP addresses from longer text:

```
\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b
```

Accurate regex to extract IP addresses from longer text:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}↵
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Simple regex that captures the four parts of the IP address:

```
^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$
```

Accurate regex that captures the four parts of the IP address:

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.↵
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.↵
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.↵
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Comment: Can you please give me advice how to edit my code regarding the examples below

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -e '$v=quotemeta($ENV{IP});print if /$v\.(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?!\d)/?1:0'
```

Comment: its not work - export IP=172.9.200 ; echo 172.9.200.10 |perl -e '$v=quotemeta($ENV{IP});print if /$v\.(?:1?\d?\d|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?!\d)/?1:0' , I dont get anything